# Append to parent's filter_horizontal in Django admin

Tags: django

Similar to how [ModelAdmin.get_fields()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fields) and other such helper functions allow you to append items on subclasses, is it possible to do this for filter_horizontal? At the moment I have to manually re-write the list on each Child admin class:

```
BaseAdminClass(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    fields = ['some_field', 'many_to_many_field']
    filter_horizontal = ['many_to_many_field']


ChildAdminClassOne(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = super(ChildAdminClass, self).get_fields(request, obj)
        return fields + ['another_field']

    # Something like get_filter_horizontal()?
    filter_horizontal = ['many_to_many_field' + 'another_field']


ChildAdminClassTwo(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = super(ChildAdminClass, self).get_fields(request, obj)
        return fields + ['other_field']

    filter_horizontal = ['many_to_many_field' + 'other_field']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it even more convenient than `fields`. Just overwrite class attribute with a property.

```
class BaseAdminClass(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['some_field', 'many_to_many_field']
    default_filter_horizontal = ['many_to_many_field']
    additional_filter_horizontal = []

    @property
    def filter_horizontal(self):
        return self.default_filter_horizontal + self.additional_filter_horizontal

class ChildAdminClass(BaseAdminClass):
    fields = ['some_field', 'many_to_many_field']
    additional_filter_horizontal = ['other_field']
```

Comment: And I would do the same with the `fields` attribute.

Comment: There's a typo in your solution, should be: `return self.default_filter_horizontal + self.additional_filter_horizontal` I accepted this as the right answer but I don't really like the fact that it introduces new arbitrary field names (i.e. additional_filter_horizontal, default_filter_horizontal). This would not be obvious to someone new looking at the code. Also, it doesn't allow to change the order of filter_horizontal fields per subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I can just simply do this on each subclass:

```
BaseAdminClass(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['some_field', 'many_to_many_field']
    filter_horizontal = ['many_to_many_field']

ChildAdminClassOne(admin.ModelAdmin):
def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = super(ChildAdminClass, self).get_fields(request, obj)
        return fields + ['another_field']

    # Something like get_filter_horizontal()?
    filter_horizontal = BaseAdminClass.filter_horizontal + ['another_field']
```

Comment: I agree that it is more simple solution. But hardcoding parent class inside child is a bad practice usually. It is better to call `super`. I assume that `ChildAdminClassOne` inherits from `BaseAdminClass`.